# change amanda backup user account on Debian

Tags: debian, amanda

Is it possible to change the account that runs the **amanda** client on a Debian host? My site is predominately CentOS 7 and all the amanda clients use **amandabackup** as the client login. I need a few Debian hosts but they all seem restricted to using **backup** as the client login.

When I test the backup from the server I get errors like this:

```
% amservice debclient bsdtcp noop < /dev/null    
Request failed: tcpm_recv_token: invalid size: "amandad: cannot look up client user \"backup\"\n"
```

I've changed the entries in `/var/lib/amanda/.amandahosts`, xinetd (and restarted) and anything I can find in `/etc/amanda*` - all to no avail.

Is it possible to change this login without building a custom client?

Alternatively - can the two accounts - amandabackup(server) and backup(deb client) live in harmony?

Answer (score -1):

A user other than `amandabackup` is not an option. Because `amandabackup` user is defined at the time of compiling only this user will have all the privileges to run *amanda* operations like `amdump`, `amstatus`. You may have to define a new user in the source code.